# Oracle LogMiner (Unsupported Operation)

Tags: oracle

I'm currently using Oracle 11g on RHEL5. I'm digging to see what are in the archived log files. After I query from v$logmnr_contents, I see many transactions of UNSUPPORTED operation.

What do these unsupported transactions mean?
I think that it's the cause that make my database generates lots of archived logs.
Moreover, I'm using global temporary table for generating reports. I discover that when I insert and delete from those temporary table, it also records in the archived log file.

How to do to reduce those recorded transactions?

Regards,

Sarith

Comment: Are you SURE they are global temporary tables ?
There isn't another table of the same name in a different schema, or a view or synonym. 
Are you doing stuff with LOBs ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that they are global temporary tables in my schema.

Answer (score 1):

The following operations are unsupported in Logminer, Oracle 11.

- BFILE datatype
- Simple and nested abstract datatypes (ADTs)
- Collections  (nested tables and VARRAYs)
- Object refs
- Tables using table compression
- SecureFiles